# Masking domain IP over redirection

Tags: redirect, web, dns, ip, subdomain

I have domain.com and redirecting its subtomain sub.domain.com to an dedicated server's IP: 0.0.0.0

When I ping sub.domain.com it gives me 0.0.0.0 - how to mask it?

@domain.com - its hosted at virtual host, and my 0.0.0.0 IP is on dedicated server. Its for online gaming

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hide the IP when it appears in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can not mask the ip if it does not match with a domain, but if it is nessessary the ip not to be visible you can add an iframe at sub.domain.com.